# How do you block chrome.tabs.executeScript()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, anti-cheat

I'm trying to get an idea of how to stop extensions from altering a client for multiplayer browser game, I've found ways to block multiple ways of doing so, however I've been looking for how to block chrome.tabs.executeScript() and i just cannot find anything or figure it out.

Comment: There's no client-side method other than using [policies](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionSettings) to set runtime_blocked_hosts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read How to Ask. and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @wOxxOm how could i do it server-side then?

Comment: There's no server-side method.

Comment: @wOxxOm so thats the only way to do it then?

Comment: Normally, yes. You can also find and exploit bugs in those extensions or in the browser itself.